# Add new features without violating basic OOP rules

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a situation where I need to extend certain behaviour and I'm stuck with how to design it right.
User can see list of all reports. Reports are simple POJOs for now

```
class Report {
  ...
}
```

There is set of actions that can be invoked on given report. Now there is a requirement that for some reports they should have defined actions that are allowed. E.g. you can run "ActionA", and "ActionB" on ReportOne, only "ActionB" on ReportTwo and all actions (as is now) on ReportThree. Also report's visibility is restricted, so that some users can't see given reports if have no sufficient rights.

I'm thinking of creating subclasses of Report like below:

```
class ReportWithCustomActionsAllowed extends Report {
  private Set<Action> allowedActions;
  public Set<Actions> getAllowedActions() {
    return actions;
  }
  ....
}

class ReportWithPermission extends Report {
  ...
  private String permissionName = "ReportA.VIEW";
  public boolean canShowTo(User user) {
    return user.hasPermission(permissionName);
  }
}
```

There are 2 things I see wrong here:

1) creating restricted report with custom actions allowed is impossible without creating another class

2) having `Set<Report>` I can't restrict action/report without hacking it with `instanceof` which is clearly wrong.

How can I realize this requirements with OOP done right? Not every report should care about permissions, and report can have empty list of actions allowed (which means that actions are not accesible to anyone. It doesn't mean all actions are allowed).

Comment: What are your Actions? Are you having it as some class?

Comment: No, they are just actions for GUI, with name and order they should appear in.

Answer (score 1):

For the actions you could probably adapt the "[Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)" design pattern.

For the access permissions, the usual way is not to have the reports care about permissions, but that have an external security manager, that maintains a list of who is allowed to do what, and when an action is invoked, checks if the role that is invoking the action is permitted to do so. This is actually a quite complicated thing to do, so you might want to specifiy more precisely how extensive your security requirements are if you want better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the full details but I would go for an abstract class `Report` and have the one abstract method `getActions(User user)` and make that method throw a `UserAccessException` or something like that.

```
abstract class Report {

abstract public Set<Action> getActions(User user) throws UserAccessException;

}
```